# How do I get the correct line number from StackTrace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stack-trace

I am writing my own poor-man's testing framework.  In my console application, I have this:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {     // Line 12
     double adouble = 77;
     double expected = 70;
     TestingFramework.assertEquals<double>(expected, adouble - 7);  // Line 15
     TestingFramework.assertEquals<double>(expected, adouble - 6);  // Line 16
   }
```

Within TestingFramework I have this line:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Success, File {0}, Line {1}", 
   new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(1).GetFileName(), 
   new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(1).GetFileLineNumber());
```

But when I run the test, it tells me that FileLineNumber is 12 for both function calls.  Further, it gives me the correct file name, so I am think it is referencing the correct frame.

Can someone tell me how I can get it to report to me the line number that originated the call (15 then 16), and not the line number of the open paren (12)?

Thanks.

Comment: You could walk up the stack looking for a class of  specific type or with an identifier of something. Loop through the Frames looking at the Methods and their owners? Just a thought

Comment: @Hans Passant:  Thanks for improving my title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem and how to fix it.

I had overloaded the assertequals function in TestingFramework: 
1) assertEquals(T expectedValue, T actualValue) and 
2) assertEquals(T expectedValue, T actualValue, string comment).

When client code calls the 2-param function, that function just calls the 3-param function.  This different frame depths depending on how it was called.

So I had to add

```
static int depth;
```

which I increment when entering a function and decrement when exiting. This changes the code to:

```
new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(depth).GetFileLineNumber());
```

and that now works.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to my comment, something like this:

```
    foreach(var frame in StackTrace.GetFrames())
    { 
        System.Reflection.MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod ( );
        Type type = method.DeclaringType;
        // If this is what I am looking for
        if ( type.IsSubclassOf( typeof(TestClassBase)) ||  type != typeof ( TestClassBase) )
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Success, File {0}, Line {1}", frame.GetFileName(), frame.GetFileLineNumber());
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in your response do you get the line number?

Comment: @philologon: He can get the line number from the stack frame he identifies as belonging to the class he is looking for.